# Changing cell color of R shiny data table dependent on its value

Tags: javascript, r, dt

I am trying to color cells that meet certain conditions. For example, I would like to color cells whose value is equal to its respective column values of the first row of the data. I figured how to color specific values using javascript but can't figure out how to set the conditions as what I want. Here's the code:

```
library(DT)
df <- head(iris)
df %>% 
  datatable %>% 
  formatStyle(1:2, color = JS("value % 1 === 0 ? 'red' : ''"))
```

In this table, the highlighted cells are the ones whose values match the value of the column of the first row of the data. I would like to set javascript conditions as such that it will highlight the cells as shown in the image.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `styleEqual` function, it almost work except that it underlines also the reference row :

```
library(DT)
df <- head(iris)
ref <- df[1,]
color <- "orange"
datatable(df) %>% 
    formatStyle(1:5,
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(ref[1:5], rep(color, 5)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to display color when you click on a specific row instead of the first row?

Comment: I don't know you just need to find a way to get row index and pass it to ref...